# Sql Developer. Как оставить только дату (без времени)

Tags: sql, oracle, дата, datetime

Как можно с даты убрать время? Думал, что так:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='dd.mm.yyyy';
```

Но все равно видно время.
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Множество нулей после запятой в вашем времени наводят на мысль, что у вас там не <s>закрытый, а открытый перелом</s> `DATE`, а `TIMESTAMP`. Соответственно, вам нужно менять его:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='dd.mm.yyyy';
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT date(`birthday`) FROM `table.name`

Answer (score 0):

TRUNC(datetime) - убирает время

Comment: Постарайтесь оставлять немного более развернутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав кнопку [edit].